# Expression tree syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda, expression

I was refactoring my old code and came upon on some syntax issue:

```
public IQueryable<T> Get_all(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, bool enableDetectChanges = true, bool enableTracking = true) {

            ActiveDbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = enableDetectChanges;

            //return all if predicate is null
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereAll = x => true;
            predicate = predicate ?? whereAll;

            var result = enableTracking ? _dbSet.Where(predicate) : _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);

            return result;
        }
```

Q: Is it possible syntax something like `predicate = predicate ?? Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereAll = x => true;` instead of 2 lines?

Thx

Comment: `predicate ?? (x => true)`

Comment: I work with expression tree and i need return expression tree, not lambda (linq to sql)

Comment: Oh;) sorry, it's  work! Great! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
predicate ?? (x => true)
```

I thought it wrong (I flound between return type Func or Expression tree), but it work. thx to PetSerAl